# react native change color one item in FlatList after click item (instagram like)

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

react native change color one item in FlatList after click item

```
<FlatList
      data={this.state.posts}
      renderItem={this.renderItem.bind(this)}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
      ListEmptyComponent={()=> <Spinner />}
      onEndReached={this.handleLoadMore.bind(this)}
      onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
      initialNumToRender={1}
/>
```

after render list click on item and change color item:

```
renderItem({item}){
return (
<Button transparent>
   <TouchableOpacity
       onPress={()=>this.likeSave(item.id) }
   >
   <Icon name="heart" size={30} style={{color:likeColor}} />
    </TouchableOpacity>
</Button>
}
```

after click Icon heart change color Icon heart to red

Answer (score 0):

The multi select example in Flatlist React Native documentation can explain how to solve your problem. Check it out here [Flatlist React Native Component](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#extradata)